# Track URL change of embed html element

Tags: javascript, html

How do you track url address/page changes of an embed element (containing a web page) in the parent web page? Ideally the page change should be detected with an event listener but polling the embed element will also work. I would like to refrain from querying elements inside the embed element for their page URL.

The `src` attribute only indicates the initial source of the embed element and does not update if the embed element's url changes.

I know you can normally query the page url with `location.href` or `document.URL` but how do you get the url source of embedded element if it changes from the source it was created with?

Comment: The html element in question is an image?

Comment: A web page. I'll update the question.

Comment: So it's an iframe? ;)